# jQuery - Exclude elements from object loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am using this code to loop through the DOM and locate all elements that match and then add a class to the elements:

```
var timeDif = 0;

setTimeout(function(){

    $('.panel-main').each(function () {
      var $el = $(this);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $el.addClass('boingInUp');
      },200 * timeDif);
      timeDif++;
    });

}, 1000);
```

what I need to know how to do is exclude any elements that have an inline style of " style="display: none; ". Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: it is true, Jason, still if it has an inline style, it does not necessary mean the element is not visible (or visible).

Comment: @skobaljic That is true, the documentation shows this in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your complete use case, you should use the jQuery visibility selector.

```
$('.panel-main:visible').each(function() {
  ...
}
```

This continues to work for elements that have that inline style, regardless if you show them or not.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var timeDif = 0;

setTimeout(function(){

    $('.panel-main').each(function () {
      var $el = $(this);
              if($el.is(':visible')){
          setTimeout(function () {
              $el.addClass('boingInUp');
          },200 * timeDif);
              }
      timeDif++;
        });

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
  $('.panel-main:visible').each(function () {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the selector

```
$('.panel-main:visible')
```

which will only return visible items